# Postgres: Concat multiple columns, while including nulls

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with four columns that I need to concat. Two of the columns contain some NULL values.

I need the result to contain separators indicating all four columns, like so:

```
colA,colB,colC,colD
```

or if one column (here colB) was null,

```
colA,,colC,colD
```

I can't seem to find a clean way to do this. The best I have come up with is:

```
concat_ws(colA, COALESCE(colB, ''), COALESCE(colC, ''), colD, ',')
```

This feels cumbersome (especially because I need to do this repeatedly). Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, but the result I get from the example above would be: colA,colC,colD. There would be no comma/separator as a placeholder for colB.

Answer (score 2):

Since the final value *can't* be NULL, you don't need to worry about preserving them. Just use an empty string. This is how you'd write it in standard SQL.

```
select coalesce(cola, '') || ', ' ||  
       coalesce(colb, '') || ', ' || 
       coalesce(colc, '') || ', ' || 
       coalesce(cold, '')
from your_table_name;
```

The concat_ws() function doesn't skip empty strings, but it *does* skip null columns. That means you still have to use coalesce().

```
select concat_ws(', ', coalesce(cola, ''), 
                       coalesce(colb, ''), 
                       coalesce(colc, ''), 
                       coalesce(colb, ''))
from your_table_name;
```

Comment: From an efficiency perspective, is the built in || better than the concat_ws function? What I had been hoping to avoid was writing the coalesce every time. (ed:spelling)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall': Postgres **does** have a `concat_ws()` function: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER (and it does skip null values as well)

Comment: Ha! Where'd *that* come from? (Introduced in 9.1.)

Comment: With concat_ws(), you still have to use coalesce() to meet your requirements for nullable columns. What I wrote is standard SQL; it will work in any SQL dbms that conforms to SQL standards.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use a cursor and then a loop also, in order to show null values you must use a nvl() function, like this:

PROCEDURE TODO IS
vAux in VARCHAR2;
CURSOR CUR_TEST IN
SELECT NVL(colb, 'replace_with'), colA, colD
FROM DUAL; 
Begin
for x in CUR_TEST loop
  vAux := x.colb||','||x.colA||','||x.colD;
end loop;

end TODO;

For checking what nvl() does: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php

Comment: First a cursor is a bad choice for this problem. Secondly this is for Postgres, not for Oracle